# django admin saving inline with blank value

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have two models as

```
class Employer(models.Model):
..
..


class JobTitle(models.Model):
    type = models.IntegerField(null=False, choices=JobTitles.CHOICES,blank=True,default=0)
    employer = models.OneToOneField(Employer,unique=True,null=False)
```

I have defined admin for `Employer` and defined `JobTitle` as inline class.

However, when I saved an `Employer` object without selecting `JobTitle`, it raises the error `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` due to the `type` field of `JobTitle`.

I would like to set `type` to 0, as I defined default=0, if I don't select any jobtitle when employer is saved.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm inferring this from the code you posted, but I think that you're mixing strategies here. I assume based on the way you've constructed your question that you want to me able to make a job title with no type. Alternatively, you want one job type to be the default selection. I further infer, although now I'm stretching a bit, that you have a custom "No Type" choice (you didn't show us your `JobTitles.CHOICES` tuple so I have to guess) that corresponds to the `0` value that you've set as the default.

If you want to have a default job type (even if you're calling it "No Job Type" or something similar), then you should set it using the `default` keyword argument (as you have done) *and* you should set `null=False` and `blank=False` (alternatively, omit both, as these are the default values).

However, if you want it to be possible that there is a job title with no type, then unless you have some reason in your implementation to do something else, the purest way to represent this in data is to use the `null` SQL value. If you want to go that route, the correct way to do it is to set `blank=True` *and* `null=True`, and then either set `default=None` or omit that keyword argument entirely.

That should get you the behavior that you seek.

Answer (score 0):

For `Model` arguments, `default` is used when Django save your data to Database...

On the other hand, your error occurs during data parsing. When you submit your form, django parses data to relevant type if needed. When your html form is submitted, django recieves string data like

```
{'title':'12', 'employer_id':'23'...}
```

So, django have to parse **type** into ineger before it save it to the database... Since your forms sends a nullstring **''** , `int('')` simply fails with TypeError.

What you must do is removing `blank=True`. Or somehow you must override the default behaviour of combobox default value and set it **0** instead of **''**.